# Are (EC) DSA blind signatures possible?

Tags: dsa, blind-signature

I've been searching for a way to create blind ECDSA signatures.
My research and experimentation has led me to believe that this is not possible.

I've been attempting to articulate why and I think that it is because it is not possible to apply a transformation to the message in a way which can be reversed whilst retaining a valid signature. The message and signature cannot be transformed as required because the ephemeral key is not known by the recipient, and if the key were known then the long term signing key could be determined. An ECDSA signature only permits validating that the signature was formed from the message and the private key corresponding to the expected public key.

I would like to confirm whether there are any known ECDSA blind signature schemes? I suppose publication bias might prevent this from appearing in the literature.

More generally are there any known ECDSA variants such as proxy signatures? My research has led me to the conclusion that it's functionality is entirely constrained to yielding a standard signature scheme.

Comment: You may also want to look at the similar _blind Schnorr signatures_.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked there but I'm ideally attempting to determine whether a 'drop-in' blind signature scheme is available for ECDSA in the same way as with RSA. I also found GDH blind signatures based on BLS.

Comment: I think the reason it's possible with Schnorr signatures is that the \[s\] value isn't a product of the ephemeral key \[k\] but rather a sum.

Comment: I believe this is possible with ECDSA, excepted that you'll be constrained when choosing the random blind since you'll need to use a blinded message whose hash is a multiple of the hash of your original message. And then use that same multiple as a blind for $R$ and $S$.

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any existing scheme allowing this easily (excepted for PureEdDSA maybe, but I wouldn't classify it as an ECDSA *variant*).

However I do not believe this is impossible. So let's try to do this for ECDSA:

We have a message $m$ whose hashed value $H(m)$ is converted into an integer $z$ which gets signed into the signature $(r,s)$ by the signer.

Now the verifier will basically rely on
$$\begin{aligned}
C&=u_1\times G+u_2\times Q\\
&=u_1 \times G +u_2d \times G\\
&=(u_1+u_2 d)\times G \\
&=(zs^{-1}+rds^{-1})\times G \\
&=(z+rds)\color{red}{s^{-1}}\times G \\
&=(z+rd)\color{red}{(z+rd)^{-1}(k^{-1})^{-1}}\times G \\
&=k\times G 
\end{aligned}$$
And will say that it verifies iff $C_x==r$
And as you can see, if you can change $r,s,z$ then you can force a coefficient in the latest line to cancel "almost out", by taking $bs,abr,abz$ instead and would end up with $$(abz+abrd)\color{red}{b^{-1}(z+rd)^{-1}(k^{-1})^{-1}}\times G \\
= ak\times G $$

Now the difficult part is to find out if it is possible to get $a,b,m'$ such that $H(m')$, once converted into $z'$ is such that $z'=abz$ and such that $(ak\times G)_x \equiv abr\mod n$...

I do not see why this couldn't be possible, being given so much slack on the variables... But since I don't have time right now to actually try it out, I'll try to do it later or another day and will edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: Great answer thank you for taking the time, I will also have a look into whether this is possible and mark once determined.

Comment: Notice that if you can provide directly the hashed value like in PureEdDSA then it's easy to do. The hard part is to find a message which gets hashed into $abz$, knowing the relationship between $a$ and $b$. But maybe there is a way to add even more slack in the process by multiplying  the $s$ value by a third variable $c$ and so we would just need to select it such that $(ack\times G)=abr$. I'll try to verify this later I've just thought of it.

Comment: @Chris Alright, my proposal is definitely not possible with ECDSA, since you have to know the $k$ value. This might be possible using deterministic ECDSA, but then it adds one more hard constraint: the modified message must then hash into a suitable $k'$, which is something pretty hard to control...

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the attempt and contribution. That's in-line with my prior findings but with a different method I hadn't considered.

Comment: I had a play with this idea just using one extra variable b. I think that if we could find a blinded message $m'$ such that $H(m):H(m')$ and then let $b=H(m')/H(m)$ then we could get this to work without knowing k. We could submit $m'$ to the signer and receive back $(r',s')$. We could unblind the message by multiplying r and s both by $b$. I think the problem, security analysis aside, is that finding a $m'$ with the required property is very unlikely given the ideally uniformly random output of the hash function.

Comment: @Chris If you are not blinding the $k$ value, then the signer is able to compute $k\times G$ out of the signature $(br,bs)$ and can find afterwards that this was the message he signed for you. I believe this is not intended in common blind schemes.

Comment: How can they compute $k\times G$ without knowledge of $b$?

Comment: Because then the $b$ cancels out with the $b$ contained in the value $(bs)^{-1}$, on line 5 of the verification process in my post (first the red $s^{-1}$ value).

Comment: How can they identify $k\times G$ in relation to $b*k\times G$? I think the signatures should look like unlinkable random tuples. Perhaps if they kept track of all the $k$ values they had generated?

Comment: @Chris  Exactly. And I think this is one of the things we want to avoid in the case of blind signatures.

Answer (score 1):

The below paper gives one;

- 2021, [One-more Unforgeability of Blind ECDSA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1449) by Xianrui Qin and Cailing Cai and Tsz Hon Yuen